# Coded UI Test - Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am using coded ui test for windows store apps.

I want to capture screen shot.

On internet I got function like

```
UITestControl.Desktop.CaptureImage();
```

But this function is available only for Desktop, not for windows phone. How to capture screen on windows phone?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898499/how-to-capture-screen-programatically-in-windows-phone-8-1-sdk) help?

Comment: @wahwahwah that's capturing within the app not a CodedUI test

Comment: As far as I know it's impossible. You might consider using the "Project My Screen" on your PC and capturing that instead.