# How can i take screen shot programatically in windows phone 8.1 silverlight application out of the application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I need to take a screen shot using my application, even out of the application when it is running in background.

In the foreground I am able to take a screen shot programatically using the below link .

[How to capture screen programatically in windows phone 8.1 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898499/how-to-capture-screen-programatically-in-windows-phone-8-1-sdk)

But when I exit out of the application I need to be able to capture a screen shot  programatically. Is it possible in windows phone 8.1 silver light application.

Comment: There's a similar question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898499/how-to-capture-screen-programatically-in-windows-phone-8-1-sdk) where you can take a screenshot of the app, when the app is in the foreground. I doubt very much  an app running as a background process could take a screen grab of whatever is on the users screen at the time the background process is invoked.

Comment: Here user has to click on takescreen shot button. But if we quit from the application it is not possible..

Comment: Why do you want your app, while running as a background process, take a screenshot of the user's phone anyway?

Comment: My application background agent will listen when ever use click on Volume up + Power button. So is there any api for it.

Comment: As far as I know, the background agent doesn't work this way. It's not permitted to listen constantly, it just gets called every 30 minutes or so.