# how to save page layout of windows app as screenshots into editable image form

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am making project of Windows Phone 8.1 application. I want to save all information of Single page as the screenshot and save into isolated storage in editable image form.

Is this possible?

[image: this image]...

Answer (score 0):

You can [render your top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280120/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-windows-phone) Grid to `WritebaleBitmap` via `render` method in silverlight apps and via `RenderTargetBitmap` [for runtime apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898499/how-to-capture-screen-programatically-in-windows-phone-8-1-sdk).